# jqgrid - update multiples rows with "custom" form like advance search

Tags: jqgrid

I need to filter (or not) records in a jqgrid and be able to update all the filtered records by changing the value (s) in one or more columns.
The solution that I thought was to have a form dialog similar to that of the advanced search where the user can select which columns he wants to update and with what values.
In this way I could call a javascript method that sends to the server the filter selected by the user + the array of columns and values ​​selected by the user.

Any recommendation?

edit: version 5.3.1

Comment: Which version of jqGrid is used?

Comment: @TonyTomov version 5.3.1

Answer (score 0):

I can recommend you to build your own form similar to the search one and set which field with what value to be updated. Clicking on a submit you will send the filter and the data fields with values which should be updated.